# How can I merge branch B with branch A, without pulling from branch A first?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm not experienced with in depth git commands, but I know the basics I think.

so my use case is, I have a 'master' branch and a 'new' branch.

master branch has a lot of files, lets say 1000 files.

I would like to have a new branch with no files, and I would like to add files to the folder in this branch, lets say 10 files,
and then I would like to add these 10 files to the master branch without first pulling from the master branch.

is this even possible?
(right now I made a new branch called 'new' using 'master' and deleted all the files in 'new', but I don't think this will work)

Comment: If you know Git 101, you won't be asking this question.  
When you create a branch on top of master, you are creating snapshot of master at that point of time and referring to that as your new branch. that means it has exactly same files and content as master while creating.

Comment: @HarishBarma ya i know that, but i was wondering if theres a way to 1 + 1 the 2 branches on the remote repo without first puling from master to new, and then pushing locally.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Why have a branch with only 10 files instead of simply 1000+10 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, basically. there won't be exist a situation like you descibe. Because, when you create new branch from master branch, at new branch allways contain files of master branch (snapshot).

Normally, we create local branch, remote branch with same name, which are distinguished by [origin](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/glossary/origin#:%7E:text=In%20Git%2C%20%22origin%22%20is,but%20just%20a%20standard%20convention.)

You should improve your basic git knowledge. Anyway, Don’t give up!

Comment: im not sure exactly how rebase works, but is it possible to
- make a new branch from master
- delete all files
- commit 1
- add files
- commit 2
- rebase to master
- remove commit 1
- confirm rebase

Comment: i dont understand exactly what you say, can you describe more clearly ?

Comment: Not quite right, you can always create an _orphan_ branch or fetch from an unrelated repository.

Comment: thanks for your knowledge that you provide.